# Parse string using RegEx and C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have the following Regular Expression-

```
 string s = "{\"data\": {\"words\": [{\"wordsText\": \"Three Elephants /d 
 in the jungle\"}]}}";

    string[] words = s.Split('\\',':','[',']','{','}','"');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
```

Which outputs-

```
data

words

wordsText

Three Elephants /d in the jungle
```

What is the best way to get rid of the first 3 lines in the output so that I only get the last line- `Three Elephants /d in the jungle`.

I believe if I were to write out all text after `"wordsText\":` this could be a possible method, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use RegEx sure, but since that looks like JSON you would be better off using JSON.NET to parse that.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
  ""Stores"": [
    ""Lambton Quay"",
    ""Willis Street""
  ],
  ""Manufacturers"": [
    {
      ""Name"": ""Acme Co"",
      ""Products"": [
        {
          ""Name"": ""Anvil"",
          ""Price"": 50
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ""Name"": ""Contoso"",
      ""Products"": [
        {
          ""Name"": ""Elbow Grease"",
          ""Price"": 99.95
        },
        {
          ""Name"": ""Headlight Fluid"",
          ""Price"": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}");

string name = (string)o.SelectToken("Manufacturers[0].Name");
// Acme Co

decimal productPrice = (decimal)o.SelectToken("Manufacturers[0].Products[0].Price");
// 50

string productName = (string)o.SelectToken("Manufacturers[1].Products[0].Name");
// Elbow Grease
```

See: [Json.Net Select Token](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SelectToken.html)

This uses the [JSON.NET Library](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Comment: You are right this is JSON, however what library does that use in .NET> As it is not recognising the JObject, I will mark as correct.

Comment: @Jambo that uses the JSON.NET library. I updated the question with a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Regex  in C# your expressions for that would be like this

```
MatchCollection matchCtrls = Regex.Matches(pageText, @"Th(.*)e", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

If you don't know what the text is going to be specifically then probably something like this

```
MatchCollection matchCtrls = Regex.Matches(pageText, @"": \(.*)\", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;